# 'Misl Lahore Taj Company'

Tags: quran, history

In many copies of Quran printed in India and Pakistan, I find this phrase 'Misl Lahore Taj Company' there on the cover page. It literally means 'Copy of Lahore Taj Company', and I interpret it as : "This Quran is a reprint from an edition published by Lahore Taj Company". My question is, what is the significance of Lahore Taj Company ? In which year was their edition of Quran published ? Does this company still exists ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but the history of a company that printed copies of the qur'an is hardly on-topic as it has no significance in relevance to the teaching of Islam.

Comment: Please tell me where should I post this question ? It is related to Islam in South-Asia.

Comment: We would rather not extend the scope of this site to questions not concerning Islam itself. But it's ok for now and you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this company still exist here is the link
https://www.tajquran.com/
sorry I have fewer reputations so I can't comment.

Comment: Thanks brother Humayun. I checked this website. They have not mentioned their history, except the year 1929. I am eager to know about this issue. Why does every other Quran published in India contains "Misl Lahore Taj Company". If you have any connections in Lahore, you might be able help me.

Comment: there are two major Quran printing companies in Pakistan Taj company & pak company, may be the quran printing in India is from Pakistan & yes I'm now in Lahore.